# Is it possible to inherit a log4j logger configuration?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Imagine I'd like to create several loggers that are basically to have the same configuration, except for 1-2 properties. Is it possible to "inherit" a logger config, and then only override single specific properties?

```
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.encoding=ISO-8859-1
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.maxBackupIndex = 5
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.maxFileSize = 128MB
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.File=c:/log.txt
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FirstFileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = [%X{uuid}] %d %p %c: %m%n

//looking for something like this
log4j.appender.SecondFileAppender=FirstFileAppender
log4j.appender.SecondFileAppender.maxFileSize = 500MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a subclass of org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator which will read the base config file into Properties object, then override some properties, possibly with properties from another file, then pass the Properties object to PropertyConfigurator.configure(Properties properties)

Comment: Well this would add logger configuration by code. I'd like to avoid this, then better having dublicate log4j.properties entries.